# HW kbd Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, crash-reports, uikeyboard

In my iOS app crash log I found this statement:

```
HW kbd Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus ios
```

Does anyone know what is this and how to resolve it?

Comment: @vrwim kindly post yout full backtrace of crash log so that i check and then guide you accordingly.

Comment: @vrwim add the exceptional break point and then check where crash occur.
Or install the app on device and then make that crash and then download the crash log and post it here.

Comment: Are you using the Unity Cloud Build Project? If so, change the version in the settings from "Always use the latest 5.x" to the exact version that you're using.

Comment: The app is built with Xamarin, and this is in the system.log of the simulator: http://pastebin.com/0ny9MPn9

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Can you check for further information in the device logs. App is probably using something without the permission. (For ex. address book requires permission on iOS 9)
please share also the iOS version.
Please check this one:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11354

Comment: I would guess HS kbd means hardware keyboard.  Did you disconnect a keyboard while you were debugging?

Comment: @OwenHartnett this crash is on device not on simulator.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Didn't find any answer yet.

Comment: It was happening to me with a React Native application. I just uninstalled the app (either on simulator or real device), and bundle it and push it again.

Comment: I have the same issue and have no idea where to search for a solution. Did you find something useful ?

Comment: No solution yet,

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this exception running a Xamarin app on the simulator. It started occurring after I toggled the software keyboard off while debugging the app. Given the exception mentioning the keyboard I think that's what caused it.

Uninstalling the app from the emulator, cleaning and rebuilding fixed the issue for me.

Unsure if this bug is on Apple's side or Xamarin's.

Answer (score 0):

The only references I could find related to Xamarin was close, but the inverse of this - [the app crashing on the simulator, but working on an actual device](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52647/app-crashes-immediately-on-start-on-ipad-runs-fine-in-simulator). The resolution in that forum post doesn't describe what the problem might be, but does suggest that cleaning the project and rebuilding may resolve it.

The specific message `HW kbd Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus ios` is related to the app crashing, but there's no additional information in [the pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0ny9MPn9) to really help pin down why it's crashing.

You might also consider adding logging statements in your code to see if you can isolate the issue.